# Update an Oracle DB with a max number for the null rows

Tags: oracle, update, max

I have an Oracle db and I need to update some columns and one of them is an number that has to be some kind of an id - max number on that column. If I use something like this:

```
update ss_chest ssc
    set SSC.NUMAR_CHEST = 'RO' || (select lpad(max(SSC.NUMAR_CHEST),5,'0')
                                   from ss_chest ssc where SSC.NUMAR_CHEST is not null)
where SSC.NUMAR_CHEST is null;
```

And the result is always the same and it updates my table with the same max NUMAR_CHEST. How can I update it always with the max number? (I have to concatenate my number with RO in front and with leading 0 on 5 spaces)
Thanks!

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking. Can you provide some sample (say 10) rows and what values you want?

Comment: I did that with a sequence. Let's say max(SSC.NUMAR_CHEST) gives me 1221, lpad(max(SSC.NUMAR_CHEST),5,'0') gives me 01221  and I wanted to update my rows where NUMAR_CHEST with RO01221, RO01222, RO01223 but with that script it updated me only with RO01221 on all rows with null NUMAR_CHEST. I made a sequence and solved my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a one-time update, or are you planning on running that query after inserts, where the insert statement is not setting SSC.NUMAR_CHEST? If you want ascending numbers, it sounds like you need to use an Oracle sequence; your subquery `(select lpad(...`  will return the max value at the point in time of the start of your query.

To use a sequence, create it once (using the name `SEQ_CHEST` in the examples below), then reference it in your update; every time you access `SEQ_CHEST.nextval` you will get a unique number:

```
create sequence SEQ_CHEST maxvalue 99999;  -- one time deal

update ss_chest ssc
   set SSC.NUMAR_CHEST = 'RO' || lpad(SEQ_CHEST.nextval,5,'0')
   where SSC.NUMAR_CHEST is null;
```

and your insert statements would be like

```
insert into ss_chest values('A', 'B', ... 'RO' || lpad(SEQ_CHEST.nextval,5,'0'));
```